# Creating a bot in discord. (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots, discord.js

Good morning! I would like to know how I can make my bot to ban words, but not just the word, I want it to ban the entire sentence that is written. I've done this, but the problem is that it doesn't ban the entire sentence.

```js
client.on('message', message => {

    if (message.content === 'BAD WORD EXAMPLE') {
        message.delete({
            timeout: 1,
            reason: 'Mensaje eliminado, contenido inapropiado..'
        });
        message.channel.send(' Mensaje eliminado por contenido inapropiado');
    }
})
```

Comment: What is the parameter `message` in your example?  It seems like that would be the whole sentence, but are you saying it's only a part of the sentence?

Comment: you would be better off using a lib which would detect obfuscated swear words https://github.com/vandie/isProfanity and add additional lists of words https://gist.github.com/lcherone/6f8043447f7f0099d430 as there is quite a few creative words people like to call each other

Answer (score 2):

If you want to simply ban the member that sent a message including `badWords`, basically you can follow @Nurfey's answer and there's much simpler code, like

```js
const badWords = ["foo", "faz", "bar"];

client.on('message', message => {
  const hasBadWord = badWords.some(banWord => message.includes(banWord))
  if(hasBadWord) {
    // delete the message
  }
});
```

If your checking will be more complex so that you want to write 2+ sentences, you can also do this:

```js
  const hasBadWord = badWords.some(banWord => {
    // multiple sentences here, and returns true or false
  })
```

The full documentation of [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is available on MDN.

Comment: this was basically what I was trying to make, but I didn't know how :-)

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've written, you could try this:

```js
const badWords = ["foo", "faz", "bar"];

client.on('message', message => {
  let hasBadWord = false;
  badWords.forEach(badWord => {
    if(hasBadWord === false) {
      if(message.includes(badWord)) hasBadWord = true; // you could do message.toLowerCase().includes(badWord) for case sensitivity
    }
  });
  if(hasBadWord === true) {
    // delete the message
  }
});
```

it's not particularly refined, but you could optimize it if you want, this is just for making it as easily readable as I can make it